# get facebook session to uses as GET params

Tags: facebook, authentication

My facebook app auth's using the php api which is great except when I need to auth on an ajax element.

When I use jquery's load to ajax an element on the page in Opera it looses authentication and then redirects to facebooks login.php and then redirects back to ajax page (which is meant to only be an element of the whole page).

Any way if it kept authentication it would not redirect... so I am thinking If I pass the session as a GET param then it wont be a problem. How can I get the session variables from $facebook?

Comment: Are you using cookie mode with the PHP SDK?

Comment: I think so... how do I turn it on?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are in an iframe app. The issue is that Opera does not allow cookies in iframe apps. All your other browsers are reading the Facebook session from the cookie, but Opera is not. So you for opera you are going to have to rely on the value of the session (or signed_request) query parameter. You should read those parameters from the querystrin. View the actual source of your iframe window. You will see your url has either a ?session or ?signed_request query parameter. After you read those values from the querystring just send them exactly as they are to your ajax call and you should be good to go. Frankly, I would just completely turn cookies off for an iFrame app. They are unreliable (read don't work on all browsers) which in my opinion means you shouldn't use them at all.

Comment: Also, see my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182064/facebook-c-sdk-ajax-in-iframe-app/4185452#4185452